# jenkinsfile not found in multi module project

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a mvn project with a parent pom that is hosted in github. each module is a microservice that is buildable using mvn + docker.

I'm trying to configure a jenkins build of one of the modules but jenkins can't find `Jenkinsfile` becuase it's not in the root( assumption)

```
--Project
   --moduleA
       /jenkins/Jenkinsfile
```

When trying to configure a Pipeline (Using Jenkins blue ocean), Jenkins can't locate any Jenkinsfile in all the project's branches.

Comment: What (relative) path did you specify in for the Jenkinsfile in the job configuration?

Comment: @yorammi I couldn't find any place to setup the jenkinsfile location. I guess that is the issue. For example [This link](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/) doesn't contain any reference on where to set up jenkinsfile path

Comment: Try in the configuration page (not in blue ocean)